# Nim is to assign variable in or beside other expression once

Tags: nim-lang

How Nim's way assign variable in or beside other expression at once, the one that'd always led to:

```
 Error: expression 's = "foo"' has no type (or is ambiguous)
```

when trying like c/c++ code `if (s = "foo").len > 5 { cout<< "Yes" ;}` or some else?
the point was that, how to have variable assignment in some expressions at once,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (let s = "foo"; s).len > 5:
  echo "Yes"
```

or

```
var s: string
if (s = "foo"; s).len > 5:
  echo "Yes"
```